# B-Tree Definition Correct or not?

Tags: binary-search-tree, b-tree

I am trying to understand the order of a B-Tree, but I am finding multiple answers. Here is what the lecturer has in the slides:

---

In a B-Tree of order n:

- The root node has between 1 and 2n keys, e.g. 1 to 4
- All other nodes have between n and 2n elements
- Root node: can have 0 or 2 to 2n+1 children, e.g. 0 or 2 to 5
- Non root node: can have 0 or n to 2n+1 children, e.g. 0 or 2 to 5

---

Some sources say that the order is the maximum number of children a nonleaf node can have.

Can someone please help me understand which is correct?

Answer (score 0):

There are indeed different, non-compatible definitions of the term "order" in the context of B-tree. Also on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree) this is mentioned:

> The literature on B-trees is not uniform in its terminology.
>
> Bayer and McCreight (1972), Comer (1979), and others define the order of B-tree as the minimum number of keys in a non-root node.
> Folk & Zoellick (1992) points out that terminology is ambiguous because the maximum number of keys is not clear. An order 3 B-tree might hold a maximum of 6 keys or a maximum of 7 keys. Knuth (1998) avoids the problem by defining the order to be the maximum number of children (which is one more than the maximum number of keys).

So, we'll have to live with this difference in terminology and always check what the author means when they use this term.